# Ubuntu is not booting even it is showing an option in boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with windows 10 on my machine, almost a month ago. For a month it was working just fine. But, since last night ubuntu is not booting, even when I start my machine, it directly boots to windows without showing a boot menu, when I press F12 for boot options, it is showing Ubuntu and windows, and even after pressing for ubuntu, still it boots to windows.

Comment: Any windows update?

Comment: I think no.. No windows update for 3-4 days.